# What is the purpose of the "robots" meta tag in HTML?

Tags: html, meta-tags

What is the following `<meta>` tag used for in HTML:

`<meta http-equiv="robots" content="no-cache" />`

Does robots mean a HTML tag name for which the cache is not done in the above example?

Comment: If you are looking for an introduction to the robots meta tag, check here: http://ligatures.net/content/expertise/how-to-use-robots-meta-tags.html

Answer (score 0):

The `http-equiv` attribute is used to specify the header type for the value of the `content` attribute; it can be used to simulate an HTTP header. I don't think `name` and `http-equiv` are exchangeable in general, but I have seen "robots" used with both, e.g.:

```
<meta name="robots" content="no-cache" />
```

[Here's a randomly-selected Google result with a list of meta names having to do with robots](http://yoast.com/articles/robots-meta-tags/). There's also [this](http://www.elated.com/articles/common-html-meta-tags/) page about common meta tags that may provide some insight; I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for with your question.

Answer (score 0):

The  tag provides metadata about the HTML document. Metadata will not be displayed on the page, but will be machine parsable.
Meta elements are typically used to specify page description, keywords, author of the document, last modified, and other metadata.

Metadata is information about data.

for eg,
The following meta element defines keywords for a page:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML, CSS, XML" />
```

Answer (score -2):

if you ask google for that meta-tag, [this](http://www.elated.com/articles/common-html-meta-tags/) is the first hit - describing a lot of things about meta-tags, and has also a paragraph about the robot-tags (which are instructions for search-engines). please try to ask google and the stackoverflow-seach before posting a questions thats so easy to find out yourself.

in addition: "no-cache" seems to be senseless in a rotobs-metatag, there should only be "index", "follow", "noindex" or "nofollow" or a combination of these like "noindex, follow". the meta-tag to tell the browser it shouldn't cache the site is

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="nocache">
                   ^not "robots"    ^without "-"
```

where have you got your example from?

Comment: "…please try to ask google and the stackoverflow-seach before posting a questions thats so easy to find out yourself.…"

This isn't the place to publicly admonish people. Additionally, Google often sucks, and your results aren't their results.